# I have 2 windows in my kitchen, would it be crazy to remove one?

Tags: kitchens, windows

Redesigning our kitchen and want to remove the stove from the island (G shape) Fridge is built-in on interior wall. Sink/dishwasher is on the far wall facing the front of the house and on the other exterior wall is an ill positioned window that would otherwise make that side of the kitchen perfect for the stove.

The dining area is behind the kitchen island (open concept) and we have a large bay window bringing in abundant light.

So, is it crazy to remove a window and replace with wall so that we can put our stove in that spot?

Comment: Would love to see a picture. Can't imagine removing a window.

Comment: Most people want more windows in their kitchen, not less.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because opinion based answer

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, any answer to this question will be a matter of opinion. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: For reference: https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: i'm shrinking a window to make everything fit in my new kitchen because it's just a bit too big to get everything fitting perfectly otherwise. If it's dark, I will add transoms windows and tube skylights. I can't see your kitchen and tradeoffs, but for me, it will make a huge difference in usability and flow, more than making up for the "loss".

Answer (score 2):

This is really an opinion question so should be closed.

I like windows but have both added them and removed them in the past. My suggestion would be to evaluate your lighting as you may need to add lights after removing a window. Dark rooms actually hurt sales especially kitchens and dining areas. So if you do remove the window (not crazy) make sure the area is still well illuminated and your new design may increase the value and functionality of your home. But I do think it is a good question + but off topic by our rules.

Comment: This is a good answer and will shed light (no pun intended) on stuff for the OP to think about.  When you really think about it, most of our answers are somewhat opinion based. +